# Angular-CLI proxy to backend doesn't work

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#proxy-to-backend here is an instruction how to do proxying to backend. I did everything step by step and still requests aren't proxied.

8080 - my Express backend
4200 - my Angular2 frontend

In Angular2 project I have file `proxy.conf.json` with content like this:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

In Angular2 package.json I changed `start` procedure to `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

When I type inside commander `npm start` then at the start I can see `Proxy created: /api -> http://localhost:8080`. Well, so far is good I guess.

I'm trying to send a request (Angular2)

```
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.getAnswer();
  }

  getAnswer(): any {
    return this.http.get("/api/hello")
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
  }
```

I'm getting an error that `http://localhost:4200/api/hello 404 (Not Found)`. As we can see, nothing has been proxied. Why? Did I do something wrong?

To be clear. When I go manually to `http://localhost:8080/hello`, all works fine. There is nothing to look for in backend side.

Comment: one thing i want to know, ur working url is http://localhost:8080/hello, then why r u pointing it to http://localhost:8080/api/hello ? have u bypassed it to your express server?

Comment: Inside proxy.cons.json I set http://localhost:8080 as /api, so when I'm pointing to /api/hello, that suppose to mean I'm pointing to http://localhost:8080/hello I guess.

Comment: New document link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy.

Comment: I know it's weird but angular proxy path is case sensitive. So defining "api" or "Api" are different in Angular proxy.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Could you try with this one:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://url.com",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

It works for me,

```
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api" ~> ""
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the `pathRewrite` placement. @elzoy: The URL is rewritten according to the regex. More info on the Webpack's Http-Proxy-Middleware: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options

Comment: i have used the above configuration..nut it still doesn't work. It shows that proxy has been set but when i make request it actually hits http://localhost:4200/api

Comment: Worked for me in development. How do I publish this to production?

Comment: @user2347528, this is not for production, this is for development purposes only. When you run ng build, you should get a small bundle with the main html file that you should be serving from your back end to display the application. Either that or you will have to set up a reverse proxy server with apache or nginx if the front end of the app will be kept separate from the back end.

Comment: If you are using an external host instead of localhost, modify target something like:
      "target": {
          "host": "url.com",
            "protocol": "http:",
            "port": 80
        },
or for secured version: just change protocol to "https:", and port to 443. Also notice there's a ':' (colon) at the end of protocol name. Also add "changeOrigin": true to your configuration.

Comment: this is not mentionned bu the official doc : https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: but what about for ng build...in ng serve it is working fine but on server it is not working. any solution for ng build?

Answer (score 29):

This was close to working for me. Also had to add

```
"changeOrigin": true,
```

full proxy.conf.json shown below:

```
{
  "/proxy/*": {
  "target": "https://url.com",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "pathRewrite": {"^/proxy" : ""}
  }
}
```

Comment: Same for me, it worked after adding `"changeOrigin": true,`
Here is my config:
`{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://url.com,
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }}`

Comment: Same - "changeOrigin" made the difference since I was trying to consume a 3rd party remote API. Otherwise the proxy config is identical.

Answer (score 13):

Please follow below steps

1. In Angular project create a file called  **proxy.conf.json** with content like this:

   ```
    {
        "/api/*": {
          "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
          "secure": false,
          "logLevel": "debug",
          "changeOrigin": true
        }
      }
   ```
2. edit package.json file and add below code in `scripts` section:

   ```
   {
     "scripts": {
       "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
     }
   }
   ```
3. call your backend api like this

   ```
   this.http.get('/api/v1/people')
       0.map(res => res.json());
   ```
4. run `npm start` or `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Comment: **proxy.conf.json** not **proxy.cons.json**  :) 
btw this was the issue with ng serve. It was some how not picking up the setting

Comment: working good with ng serve , but not working on prod mode (i use appache server with xamp) any idea ?

Answer (score 11):

I had to make a small adjustment based on the above answers, although it seems a bit odd looking at the config now.

This is my proxy.conf.json shown below:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
     "target": "https://url.com",
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "debug",
     "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : "http://url.com/api"}
  }
}
```

Basically, I rewrote the path completely. And it works now.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but your method does not work. Maybe you have any ideas?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872498/configure-angular-cli-proxy-for-custom-headers-in-request-to-backend

Thanks

Comment: I checked your other question - have one doubt - why is the pathrewrite like this?   
`"^/profile": ""`
Shouldn't you have a destination/result path?

Comment: Thanks a lot!

{
  "/profile/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8888",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/profile": "http://localhost:8888/profile"
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}

Comment: This is very strange, after restarting the idea again does not work. Cleaned the entire cache. ((((((

Comment: Can you paste the code snippet of yours here? Or is it the same as the one in your previous comment?

Comment: Also, I dont think there should be semicolons after "localhost:8888" and "localhost:8888/profile".

Comment: I think that again I found a mistake. My API in the code did look like that http://localhost:8888/profile, after change to /profile  everything worked again. Now I'm looking for information and can not find how to set up a proxy for the production(by ng build). You know? At me there the server too works on other address. Thank you so much.

Comment: In all examples, it is said that there is no need to configure a proxy for the production. And how do I then indicate my root URL. If my api looks like this now /profile ... etc? Thanks

Comment: Incase you want to have a base URL for your production build, then I suggest having a global variable in your app, (in some service maybe) then all your other URLs can be baseurl + '/someurlhere'

Comment: Did as you said. Global variables inserted from environments. Everything is in order, but in the request my custom header again is missing. In what there can be a reason why angular in productive version overwrite my custom heders in request? Thanks for the help.

Comment: This discussion is getting too long. Mind if we switch over to your question and continue this there? Also, if it helped do upvote and accept my answer :)

Comment: Thanks. If you know the answer, I will be grateful for your reply. If not, then I will have to create a new topic, because I have not found a solution. And I'm more of a backend programmer myself.

Comment: You can also set like this. { "/api": { "target": "https://url.com/api",
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "debug",
     "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}

Comment: "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : "http://url.com/api"}   It worked for me in Angular 15

Answer (score 5):

> On **MAC** this works for me

Angular 4 running **localhost:** **http://localhost:4200/**

> In **package.json**

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
```

> In **proxy.config.json**

Where ***our-company-server*** would be replaced by off-site **URL**

```
{
  "/v1": {
    "target": "https://our-company-server.com:7002",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

> Where an angular **GET** request would be...

```
this.http.get('/v1/dashboard/client', options).map...

// options are headers, params, etc...
// then .map the observable in this case.
```

Answer (score 2):

For those having a custom localhost domain, refer to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4676#issuecomment-367270531) solution

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://backend.site.example",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "http://backend.site.example/api"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this work for me proxy.config.json file

```
{
"/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

and add "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json" in package.json
and run command npm start

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know why but in angular 11, the only solution that worked for me was the following proxy.conf.json (without any other arguments):

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Furthermore, in angular 11, you have the option to set in the angular.json the correct proxy configuration without setting it as argument to npm commnand:

```
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "angular-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
...
```

Comment: Addition to `angular.json` is actually the necessary part.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy attribute **pathRewrite** should be added in the proxy.conf.json.
See the example below.

```
{
  "/services/*": {
    "target": "http://yoururl.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin" : true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/services" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

and run **ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json**
Surely it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things, mostly it will be either of these:

1. Add the following:

   ```json
   "changeOrigin": true,
   "pathRewrite": {"^/service" : ""}
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the question, but make sure your backend is actually available where you expect it to be. In my case something made the node.js backend stop answering requests which I didn't notice at first and blamed the proxy.