# Angular-cli: Can not set proxy

Tags: angular, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

My angular-cli version is **1.4.4**, I follow the construction here to set backend proxy:
[How to set backend proxy with angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

So I generate a file called proxy.conf.json next to package.json, the content is:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

However, When I type command `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`, I didn't see any tip to say proxy has been set, the output is :
[image: startup info]
As you can see, it only has info of webpack compiling, no info about `[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  http://localhost:8080` has been outputed.

And now I have an api call, the api route is `/api/authenticate`. I suppose it should redirect to `http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate`, however it didn't, still point to `http://localhost:4200/api/authenticate`, of course it return **404 not found**. Can anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved the problem by adding "**pathRewrite**" key to the JSON.

So change your proxy config file to this.

```
{
 "/api": {
 "target": "http://localhost:8080",
 "secure": false,
 "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : "/api"}
 }
}
```

And yes, the webpack compiling did not show any info about my proxy configuration as well.

**EDIT 1:** If you are still not getting it, check this link
[Angular-CLI proxy to backend doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809008/angular-cli-proxy-to-backend-doesnt-work)

Also run your server using "serve" instead of "start". For instance

> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

Comment: Still not work for me... What's your angular-cli version?

Comment: Now I have added a link that mainly discusses about this problem. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using Angular version 4.1.3 and cli version 1.0.4 and compiler-cli version 4.1.3

Comment: It didn't work either, feel mad at this issue... but thanks for your help. Now I have to add cors support in server side to continue my work.