# How to dynamically change request in proxy.conf.js before it's sent

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I have an Angular7 application and want to send a HTTP request to an API via an Angular CLI proxy. The API then responds with a JSON object. My configurations for the proxy are done in a proxy.conf.js.

A simple request with a simple target works fine. But I want to dynamically change the request before it's sent. I found an instruction at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md#bypass-the-proxy but I just can't make it to work to dynamically change the target url.

**My goal:**
I want to send a request to a weather API. The url I send to that API must contain the latitude and longitude of a city. The city will be selected by a user. This user input should change the request target.

**The request I am sending:**
`http://localhost:4200/forecast?lat=51.33962&lon=12.37129`

**This is my proxy.conf.js:**

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/forecast",
        ],
        target: "https://api.anyName.net/forecast/anyKey/37.8267,-122.4233",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: {
            "^/forecast": ""
        },
        bypass: function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
            if (req.query.lat) {
                let LATITUDE = req.query.lat;
                let LONGITUDE = req.query.lon;
                const newTarget = "https://api.anyName.net/forecast/anyKey/"+LATITUDE+","+LONGITUDE;               
                req.target = newTarget;
                return newTarget;
            } 
        },
    }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

I am not quite sure how to use the bypass function. What could I do to change the target?

Comment: Did you try using environment variables ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. For this setup to work, I think your target on proxy config should be `"https://api.anyName.net/forecast/anyKey"`. Also, if you need to adjust the path or some constant on the request according to the environment (dev, qa, prod, etc), a better way to do this is using environment files strategy already provided by angular cli. If you need to always change your requests according to some condition, a better approach is using an `interceptor`.

Answer (score 2):

Well I managed to achive what I wanted. I did miss out that what I am doing in this line `pathRewrite: {"^/forecast": ""},` is actually a RegEx with what I can manipiulate the request that will be send. So I did the following:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/forecast",
        ],
        target: "https://api.anyName.net/forecast/anyKey/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: function(path) {
            const parameter = path.split("?")[1];
            const latitude  = parameter.split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
            const longitude = parameter.split("&")[1].split("=")[1];

            return path.replace(path, `${latitude},${longitude}`);
        },
    }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

I did find helpfull docs here https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options and got the hint there [Angular-CLI proxy to backend doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809008/angular-cli-proxy-to-backend-doesnt-work)