# Call to AWS api from Angular 9 giving cors error

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, post, cors

I am writing a post method in Angular 9 which calls an AWS API. However, when I call the post function in Angular 9 : `this.http.post(url, body, requestOptions)`, in my browser I get the following error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' as been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` I have enabled CORS on my AWS API (and deployed it). Also, I have include the following `proxy.conf.json` in my `angular.json`:

`{`

```
"/api/*": {
"target": "url",
"secure": true,
"changeOrigin": true
}
```

}

but I am still getting the cors error. I have tested my POST request using Postman, and the request runs perfectly. Is there a way to resolve this CORS error?

Comment: Did you try secure: false ? I think  you can find some solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809008/angular-cli-proxy-to-backend-doesnt-work.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you follow the [Enabling CORS for a REST API resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) on AWS docs.

Since the request works from postman that gives us a hint that the issue is most likely client-sided.