# http get request to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed fails with CORS

Tags: api, http, proxy, get, cors

I want to read the StackOverflow job RSS feed, I tried adding "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" and proxy implementation as well, it errors out. Please help me to achieve this [SOLVED, Please see the answer below]

API URL: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed

```
  private proxyPrefix = '/api';
  private hostName = 'stackoverflow.com';
  private location='sydney'
  private query = `location=${this.location}`;
  private path = 'jobs/feed';
  
  private stackOverFlowJobsRssFeedUrl = `${this.hostName}/${this.path}?${this.query}`;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private getData$(url: string): Observable<any> {
    const requestOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*' }) };
    return this.http.get<any>(url, requestOptions);
  }
    
  private get stackOverflowJobs$(): Observable<any> {
    const proxyURL = `${this.proxyPrefix}/${this.path}?${this.query}`;
    return fromFetch(proxyURL, {
      selector: response => response.json()
    });
  }
    
  ngOnInit(): void {

    // http get
    this.getData$(this.stackOverFlowJobsRssFeedUrl)
      .subscribe((x) => {
        console.log(x);
      });
    
    // rxJs fetch using proxy
    this.stackOverflowJobs$.subscribe({
      next: result => console.log('jobs:',result),
      complete: () => console.log('done')
    });

  }
```

```
proxy.config

{
  "/api/jobs": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "https://stackoverflow.com",
       "protocol": "https:",
       "port": 443
     },
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

Error

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/jobs/feed?location=sydney from localhost:4200 to https://stackoverflow.com (ENOTFOUND) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that CORS is allowed on the SO server-side? Try to send this from SO and another domain console in dev tools, you will get a response only from SO.
One of the options is to set up some server and use it as middleware, then the CORS issue will be not relevant

```
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // this will be a string
});
```

Comment: I guess CORS is not allowed at the server end, that why I'm trying with proxy. It should be possible with proxy, but don't know how to achieve it successfully

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "/proxy/*": {
  "target": "https://stackoverflow.com",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "pathRewrite": {"^/proxy" : ""}
  }
}
```

This proxy config solved my problem :)

StackOverflow Ref: [Angular-CLI proxy to backend doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809008/angular-cli-proxy-to-backend-doesnt-work)