# Error: 422 (Unprocessable Entity). Angular4

Tags: angular, http-post, http-status-code-422

I am trying to post data from Angular4 on localhost:4200 to an API on localhost:8000. I works fine with Postman, but not with Angular. Then I get:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

This is the service that posts to api:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    login(username: string, password: string): Observable<Response>{
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/login';
        const json = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
        const headers: Headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        return this.http.post(url, json, headers )
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

This is the code that runs the method

```js
   logIn(user: string, password: string){
      this.apiService.login(user, password).subscribe(
          data => console.log(data),
          error => console.log(error)
      );
    }
```

Comment: why'd you define the method inside the constructor?

Comment: I don't. I define the object http. It's the angular-way of doing it.

Comment: i see sorry i didn't see the { }

Comment: Did u find a solution @Skvupp

Comment: Yes, it was a server-problem using the Lumen framework. The Angular code was correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807666/different-ports-for-frontend-and-backend-how-to-make-a-request

Answer (score 2):

I am also getting same issue while using the 'angular-in-memory-web-api'. The problem was while creating the InMemoryDbService i have not added the primary key like id. after added the id in createDb instance it's working fine for me.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService implements InMemoryDbService {

  constructor() { }
  createDb() {

    let users = [
      {**id: 1**, username: "Sandy", firstname: "Sandesh", lastname: "K", password: 
        "XXXX", description: "Hi, Going to save data", gender: "Male" }
    ];
    return { users };

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
>   understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
>   415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
>   syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
>   instructions.

For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into you backend, in delete fuction, it's common happens when you call DELETE method and try to processos some data from body, but DELETE don't have a body, take a look if u don't have in your delete something like:

```
err := c.BodyParser(&user)
```

here BodyParser is the problem, u can't do it cuz you dont have a body